# What can be done if ChatGPT 3.5 becomes unresponsive while working on an answer?

Tags: chatgpt

I ask questions using the normal prompts in Open AI's web application [ChatGPT 3.5](https://chat.openai.com).

After entering a question, ChatGPT seems to be stuck and doesn't respond or show any activity even after several minutes. For example:

[image: "ChatGPT" label with toolbar underneath and no response between the two where it should be "typing" something]

or:

[image]

which changes every second to a slightly smaller dot:

[image]

Or in times, it also just freezes.

I found information online about similar experiences, [CHAT GPT [sic] 4 Painfully slow, I know why, with a quick solution](https://community.openai.com/t/chat-gpt-4-painfully-slow-i-know-why-with-a-quick-solution/502218).

I haven't tried closing or refreshing the page even after more than five minutes because in the past, in other web applications, this has caused me to lose my session history.

What can be done to get ChatGPT to start responding again without losing the session history?

Comment: This is linked to meta [Where should questions about ChatGPT troubleshooting be asked on Stack Exchange? I guess on Web Applications SE? And if not, where do they fit?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/253420).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After waiting more than 10 min I finally risked refreshing the page using <kbd>F5</kbd>.

After refreshing the page, I immediately received ChatGPT's answer. The session history was also intact.

Refreshing the page prior to receiving an answer does not seem to do any damage and is a good option to try if the session is laggy or Chat GPT becomes unresponsive for a long time.

Comment: "Most" web browsers have a set of features usually referred to as "developer tools". I suggest you spend some time learning about them, first, to learn that they exist, their name, and what they do without going deep into the details about how to use them. Focus on learning what exists at your fingertips.